# Custom MonadState instance

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

When I do:

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal update
cabal install hakaru
cabal repl
λ> :l simple.hs 
λ> sample test []
```

with `simple.hs` containing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Language.Hakaru.ImportanceSampler
import Control.Monad.State
instance MonadState Int Measure
test :: Measure Int
test = put 1 >> get >>= \i -> return i
```

my computer runs out of memory.

How can I successfully make the `Measure` monad an instance of `MonadState` (i.e. have `test` above return `1`)? The `Measure` type is already an instance of `Monad` with `bind` and `return` defined. Is there some default way I can define `MonadState`'s `put` and `get` in terms of `lift`, `bind`, and `return` to make it work? I tried:

```
get = lift   get
put = lift . put
```

but I couldn't get the (transformer?) types to work out:

```
simple.hs:6:9:
    Couldn't match type ‘t0 m0’ with ‘Measure’
    Expected type: Measure Int
      Actual type: t0 m0 Int
    In the expression: lift get
    In an equation for ‘get’: get = lift get

simple.hs:7:9:
    Couldn't match type ‘t1 m1’ with ‘Measure’
    Expected type: m1 () -> Measure ()
      Actual type: m1 () -> t1 m1 ()
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘lift’
    In the expression: lift . put
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Measure` is already defined in a following way:

```
newtype Measure a = Measure { unMeasure :: [Cond] -> Sampler (a, [Cond]) }
```

You can see that there is no place to store your `Int`, so you cannot make it a proper instance of `MonadState`. 
If you want to extend `Measure` to `MonadState`, you can use `StateT` monad transformer:

```
test :: StateT Int Measure Int
test = put 1 >> get >>= \i -> return i
```

What happened here? `StateT s` is a monad transformer, which lets you to combine `State s` monad with any other monad (in this example `Measure`)

Comment: I think I need the opposite stack order - something like `test :: Measure (State Int ())`, since I want to do `sample :: Measure a -> [] -> IO [(a,P)]` on the return value of `test`.

Trying this out now... Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @KarlC the StateT monad does internally "reverse orders"; all monad transformers do. For example, `MaybeT` is defined as: `newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT {runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a)}`, so `MaybeT IO ()` is the type of an I/O program which, if it completes, will either contain `Nothing` or else `Just ()`. Similarly, `StateT` is defined as `newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}`, so once you `runStateT test startState` you will have a `Measure (Int, Int)` instance.

Comment: The `test :: StateT Int Measure Int` is doing the trick for me now, along with `runStateT` to get a `Measure (Int,Int)` out. Still trying to wrap my head around what is specific to the `MaybeT` and `StateT` examples from the online Haskell wiki, and what can be generalized to other monads...

Answer (score 0):

The exact code which ended up working for me is:

```
import Language.Hakaru.ImportanceSampler
import Language.Hakaru.Distribution
import Control.Monad.State
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

test1 :: StateT Int Measure Int 
test1 = do
  i <- lift $ unconditioned $ categorical [(0,0.25), (1,0.25), (2,0.5)]
  j <- lift $ unconditioned $ categorical [(i,0.25), (1,0.25), (2,0.5)]
  put (i + j)
  k <- get 
  return k

run_test1 = unsafePerformIO $ empiricalMeasure 10 (evalStateT test1 0) []
```